# MS CRM Online & VS 2013 BIDS - Not option for Dynamic CRM Fetch Type

Tags: c#, mailchimp

I have VS 2013,MS CRM 2016 Online, Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Report Authoring Extension, but there is no option "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch" in Type.

Please find attached screenshot for more detail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjlbs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because Visual Studio 2013 is not supported. You will need to use VS2012/2010.

> The following components are required:
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012
>
> -- OR --
>
> Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Data Tools
>           To install SQL Server Data Tools, on the PC running Visual Studio 2010 go to the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express download page, download the following files appropriate to your CPU architecture and language:
>               ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
>               ENU\x86\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe
>           Select the "SSDT" or "SQL Server Data Tools" installation

[More information](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50375)